# Rows are still present after calling delete() in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I want to have a Flask route that deletes all instances of a SQLAlchemy model, `VisitLog`.  I call `VisitLog.query.delete()`, then redirect back to the page, but the old entries are still present.  There was no error.  Why weren't they deleted?

```
@app.route('/log')
def log():
    final_list = VisitLog.query.all()
    return render_template('log.html', loging=final_list)

@app.route('/logclear')
def logclear():
    VisitLog.query.delete()
    return redirect("log.html", code=302)
```

```html
<a href="{{ url_for('logclear') }}">Clear database</a>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just like other write operations, you must commit the session after executing a bulk delete.

```
VisitLog.query.delete()
db.session.commit()
```